# Solr for PHP: getDigestedResponse not working

Tags: php, solr, simplexml

I've managed to install Solr for PHP on my Windows 7 64bit Machine using the plugin I found here:

downloads.php.net/pierre/

It was linked to on this site:

wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP

(links are not clickable because I'm a new user)

I've got everything up and running, searches and indexing are working, but only when I use the [getRawResponse()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/solrresponse.getrawresponse.php) Method and parse it through SimpleXml (http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).
The [getDigestedResponse()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/solrresponse.getdigestedresponse.php) method, which ist supposed to return a PHP-Object, just returns `string(1) " "`.
The method getResponse() (http://docs.php.net/manual/en/solrresponse.getresponse.php) just times out.

It wouldn't be that much of a problem, but some of the XML from the Raw Response doesn't seem to be valid and parsed with simpleXML, some of the attributes are missing, using regular expressions to get the needed data would be too much of a hassle.

Has anyone get this to work yet? Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are parsing the response. Try code below and drop the PHP/PECL solr libs and go CURL (*ex: hostNameHere:8983/solr/select/?q=solr&start=0&rows=10&indent=on and send the result XML to the function below*).

If you can access a resource (solr) via a URL, then there is no need to use an ancillary library to do what CURL can do:

```
function makeSimpleXML($xml) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    if (!$dom) {
        // ErrorUtility::throwFatal("could not parse xml. please check the format", "XMLParisng Error");
    }
    return simplexml_import_dom($dom);
}
```